# sort the array that consists of objects that have array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

here is my array of object within objects example:

```
var ActivitiesObject = [{
    activities: [{
        id: someid
        order: 1
    }, {
        id: someid
        order: 0
    }]
}, {
    activities: [{
        id: someid
        order: 0
    }, {
        id: someid
        order: 1
    }]
}];
```

What I am trying to do is to sort this ActivitiesObject so that objects inside activities would be in order based on order number so after sort is done, it should look something like this:

```
var ActivitiesObject = [{
    activities: [{
        id: someid
        order: 0
    }, {
        id: someid
        order: 1
    }]
}, {
    activities: [{
        id: someid
        order: 0
    }, {
        id: someid
        order: 1
    }]
}];
```

Now, I tried this:

```
ActivitiesObject.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.activities.order - b.activities.order;
});
```

But that didn't work. What is the right syntax or way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to sort the `activities`, not the `ActivitiesObject`, so you should iterate over the outer array, sorting each of the inner arrays.

```
ActivitiesObject.forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.activities.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.order - b.order;
    });
});
```